# CUDA functions failing after initializing Spinnaker API

Tags: c++, cuda

I am using the C++ [Spinnaker API](http://softwareservices.flir.com/Spinnaker/latest/index.html) to capture images from cameras, and then using CUDA to process the images. The CUDA code works if I do not call the Spinnaker API, but once I call the Spinnaker API various CUDA functions start crashing (such as cudaMemset, or cudaMemcpy, or my custom CUDA kernels). The Spinnaker API works if I do not use CUDA code, so it is like the two API's cannot co-exist. The error is consistently:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error' what():  Bad address
```

The code looks like this:

```
// get cameras
SystemPtr system = System::GetInstance();
CameraList camList = system->GetCameras();

// fails on any of the following CUDA functions
cudaMemset(...);
myKernel();
cudaMemcpy(...);
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: That error comes from within the C++ standard library, and it is usually related to your system running running out of a resource (like threads, processes, semaphores, shared memory). Check your system logs and see if the kernel or syslog contains any errors

Comment: Thanks, I am allocating almost all shared memory(gpu/cpu) on this jetson device so maybe this camera api is consuming too much memory after the CUDA allocations. I changed the USBFS settings to lower the camera transfer max to 200MB though and at 480x640 mono8 it should be small enough. I also used small images for the CUDA allocation and it still didn’t help.

Comment: I doubt this is memory related -- you should get the kernel OOM killer telling you if you are using too much memory. It is more likely to be other resources like total processes or threads or something like that

Comment: Thanks. I ended up downgrading the software and it fixed it. I guess the new version was maybe consuming more memory than the older version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading from spinnaker-2.6.0.160 to spinnaker-2.0.0.146 fixed this issue on ARM64 Ubuntu 18.04.